# How to use localization in Javascript functions .net core

Tags: javascript, .net-core, localization

I cannot localize a string to present a javascript alert to the user.
@Localizer works in my views outside of javascript in HTML:
    @Localizer["messageToLocalize"];

Here is my code block inside  tags:

The commented-out line returns this javascript error in Chrome Developer Tools:

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

But of course outside of a javascript block it works: @Localizer["Please select a Provider"]

How can I localize the string I want to return to the user?

```
if (providerIndex < 1) {
//alert(@Localizer["Please select a Provider"]);
alert("Please select a Provider");
return
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I figured it out, perhaps this will help someone else.
All I had to do is put the entire Localizer text in single quotes:

Instead of:
    alert(@Localizer["Please select a Provider"]);

Do it this way:
    alert('@Localizer["Please select a Provider"]');

This works as expected.